# Does redis ever search in its database (persisted data) for a key?

Tags: redis

I understand redis can persist data, but during operation, when you look up a key on a redis server, does it ever need to go look for that key in the persisted data (files), or does it ONLY look for it in in-memory cache? What if the key is not found in the cache, does it automatically try to look for it on disk? How does it deal with cache being too big, if it writes the cache to memory, does it then clear the cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a in-memory data store. It can only hold a data set that can be fit into memory. Data in memory is NOT cache, but the whole data set. Redis can persist data on disk. However, the disk data is used for recovery, NOT for search. See the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) for details.

> does it ever need to go look for that key in the persisted data (files), or does it ONLY look for it in in-memory cache?

NO. It never looks up a key in the persisted data.

> What if the key is not found in the cache, does it automatically try to look for it on disk?

NO.

> How does it deal with cache being too big, if it writes the cache to memory, does it then clear the cache ?

You can configure a policy to evict keys when the memory is insufficient. See the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) for details.

Comment: This means it's not really a database is it ? It can only persist as much as it can hold in memory. But if I have an ever increasing number of key/value pairs and i need ALL of them persisted, i cannot use Redis as it'll eventually start to reject keys from cache to  keep all in memory.

In that case, I have to use another db behind redis for storage, and at my application level write both to that db and redis, like a traditional cache?

Comment: If your data set is too large to fit into memory of a single machine, you can also use `Redis Cluster` to store these data in multiple machines. Otherwise, as you said, you can have other database as the main db, and use Redis as an LRU cache.

Answer (score 2):

All keys in Redis are always in memory. Data persisted to disk is **only** accessed during bootstrap for recovery purposes.